# Pass Variable from View to Template in Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I have a layout template with a view set like this:

```
layout
    header
    container
        h2.page-title
        content-box
            yield
        sidebar
```

and

```
view
    section-title
        content
```

What I'm trying to do is have the page title render in my layout. I'm doing this for stylistic reasons.

I could put the view specific title in the view file, then use CSS to offset it `-100px` or something. Can I pass a variable from the view to the layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone has this issue, like `@Rails Fan` said, I used a content_for helper (not quite what was linked to though, which is why I have my own answer).

My layout view:

```
header
container
    <%= yield :custom_section %>
    content-box
        yield
    sidebar
```

My view:

```
<% if content_for :custom_section %>
  <h1>Page Title</h1>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve is usually done with the content_for helper. See [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-the-content-for-method)

It actually uses the title in the example, so you could just copy paste.

Edit: Sorry, I mixed the HTML page's title with the page's title you want, as you pointed out, so the example is not good for you without changing it. But it seems the guide helped you to figure out what you need.